# Private is not valid AND local function is declared but never used errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having these two issues that I can't resolve. 
The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item. 
AND
The local function OnTriggerEnter2D is declared but never used. Can anyone take a look and help me figure what the issue is?

Thank You!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour

{
    private object collision;
    public float _speed = 3.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Laser")
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }

            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

                if (transform.position.y < (-5.71f))
                {
                    float Randomx = Random.Range(-5, 5);
                    transform.position = new Vector3(Randomx, 5.71f, 0);
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have placed `OnTriggerEnter2D` method inside of `Update` method. I don't think you meant to do that.

Comment: Did you mean to also call `OnTriggerEnter2D` inside of `Update`?  Because just defining a local method like that does not mean it will be called from the enclosing method.

Comment: Thanks @juharr and  I have moved it out of void update and it fixed the initial problem, but now i am getting a cs1525 'end of file' unexpected symbol error.

Comment: Just balance your brackets.

Comment: got it. thanks for helping out everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can have functions inside functions (more about [Local Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). To fix the error, do either this:

## Pull out the function from inside `Update`

```
private void Update() { }
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Laser")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position.y < (-5.71f))
    {
        float Randomx = Random.Range(-5, 5);
        transform.position = new Vector3(Randomx, 5.71f, 0);
    }
}
```

Or this:

## Remove accesibilty from local method (they can't be private/public, etc)

```
private void Update() 
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Laser")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.y < (-5.71f))
        {
            float Randomx = Random.Range(-5, 5);
            transform.position = new Vector3(Randomx, 5.71f, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Of course, if you use `OnTriggerEnter` inside another method, Unity won't be able to find it so the code won't work.

Comment: While that helps explain local methods, that would not help the OP as Unity would not recognize the OnTriggerEnter2D event.